# import null value (date type) from txt file to oracle by Oracle SQL developer

Tags: oracle, date, null

i have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE tmpTable 
( 
  firstDay date, 
  lastDay date, 
  description char(50) 
);
```

i have a text file include these data:

```
-------------------------
| 08/27/2017 null "khanh" | 
| null 08/27/2017 "khanh" |
```

i used Oracle SQL Developer to load data from .txt file to my table but it doesn't recognize the null field

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoSnZ.png)

How can i import data in .txt file with null value

Comment: Is that screenshot correct? It looks like you're selecting column4, and in your file there are only 3 columns, which is why they are all showing as NULL.

Comment: Not only what bbrumm wrote; your CREATE TABLE does not have a column named SOD_REQ_DATE, and your text file has dates in the `mm/dd/yyyy` format but SQL Developer shows `YY-MON-DD`. So, please explain why we should believe anything you write.

Answer (score 1):

i found out the solution, just leave it withouth any space 
Ex: (i replaced spacebar by '_', but in txt file it still is 08/27/2017 null "khanh"). 
 
08/27/2017_null_"khanh"  => 08/27/2017__"khanh"